# Fetching all those text that match a pattern using shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

html file that i have to read line by line. I then need to run a script that matches some class attribute of span tag and then returns the text enclosing the span and the line number on which it exists.

Following is my single line code of .html file:

```
<span id="L9_454" class="e"><span class="ln">454</span><span class="bar"></span>                      <span class="k">if</span> ( (strncmp(<span class="fm" value="2705">p_rout</span>-&gt;<span class="fm" value="186">source_corresp</span>.<span class="fm" value="105">name</span>, <span class="fm" value="5190">IL_LOWERING_INIT_ROUTINE_PREFIX</span>, strlen(<span class="fm" value="5190">IL_LOWERING_INIT_ROUTINE_PREFIX</span>)) == 0) </span>
```

i need to run the script on every line and search if class="fm" is set for any span tag then i need to dump the line no i.e 454 in above example and text that have span class="fm" i.e p_rout,source_corresp,name,IL_LOWERING_INIT_ROUTINE_PREFIX and IL_LOWERING_INIT_ROUTINE_PREFIX in a .xml file.

i know how to dump the data but i just dont know how can i get the texts required. I tried it using awk but cudn't get what regex should i match. Any other filter would also work. Pls help

Comment: You are probably better off using a HTML parser for this.

Comment: To add to [devnull](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull)'s answer, try using [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) and some XPath library in the language of your choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '$1 ~ /fm/ {print $2}' RS=span FS='[<>]'
```

- set Record Separator to `span`
- set Field Separator to `<` or `>`
- if field one contains `fm` print field two

Result

```
p_rout
source_corresp
name
IL_LOWERING_INIT_ROUTINE_PREFIX
IL_LOWERING_INIT_ROUTINE_PREFIX
```

Comment: Would match `$1` like `fme`,`sofm` etc.

Comment: +1 but I think `awk '$1 ~ /"fm"/ {print $2}' RS=span FS='[<>]'` will be safer command as it won't accidentally match `class="fma"`